# search in JSON File, using a loop

Tags: java, for-loop, search

I created a JSON file with JAVA.
Now I want to search a String in the JSON file.

```
            JSONObject root = new JSONObject();

            JSONObject courseObject1 = new JSONObject();
            courseObject1.put("name", "MEA");
            courseObject1.put("author", "Mn");


            root.put("object", courseObject1);

            //------------------------------------

             JSONObject courseObject2 = new JSONObject();
             courseObject2.put("name", "MES");
             courseObject2.put("author", "Ma");


             root.put("object2", courseObject2);
```

I want to know in which courseObject is "MES".

(Maby in the finish programm are more courseObjects)

Answer (score 0):

You can proceed as follows:

```
for(int i = 0; i < root.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject obj = root.getJSONObject(i);
    if(obj.getString("name").equals("MES")) {
        // Do something with the course
    }
}
```